# MatLab Function - Error in first line for no reason?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a code that will find the roots of a function using the bisection method.

The issue that I'm running into is that when I run the function I get the error:

> Error in bisect (line 3).

I'm not sure why defining y is an error? I was looking online and it said I could be confusing functions and scripts, but I'm not sure why in other codes I can define a new variable in this why but in this particular one, I cannot.

Any help?

```
function [flag,root] = bisect(a,b,c,d,A,B)

y = a*A^3 + b*A^2 + c*A + d;
z = a*B^3 + b*B^2 + c*B + d;

% Opposite Signs    
if y < 0 && z > 0
    flag = ['There exists a root in [',num2str(A),',',num2str(B),'].'];

    m = (A+B)/2;
    testm = a*m^3 + b*m^2 + c*m + d;

        while testm < 0
            m = (A+m)/2;
            testm = a*m^3 + b*m^2 + c*m + d;

            if testm == 0
                root = m;
                break
            end

        end



    elseif ((a*A^3 + b*A^2 + c*A + d) < 0 && (a*B^3 + b*B^2 + c*B + d) > 0)
        flag = ['There exists a root in [',num2str(A),',',num2str(B),'].'];

        m = (A+B)/2;
        testm = a*m^3 + b*m^2 + c*m + d;

        while testm < 0
                m = (B+m)/2;
                testm = a*m^3 + b*m^2 + c*m + d;

                if testm == 0
                    root = m;
                    break
                end

        end

    elseif ((a*A^3 + b*A^2 + c*A + d) > 0 && (a*B^3 + b*B^2 + c*B + d) > 0) 
        flag = ['There does not exist a root in [',num2str(A),',',num2str(B),'].'];
        root = 'Does not Exist';
    elseif ((a*A^3 + b*A^2 + c*A + d) < 0 && (a*B^3 + b*B^2 + c*B + d) < 0)
        flag = ['There does not exist a root in [',num2str(A),',',num2str(B),'].'];
        root = 'Does not Exist';            
end      
end
```

## Edit:

I'm inputting (0,1,0,-2,0,4) since I know the roots of that function and am trying to test it out.

Comment: What are the arguments `a, b, c, d, A, B` you are calling your function with? And what is the exact error (appart from the line number)?

Comment: The error that I wrote is EXACTLY what I'm getting out of it, that's why I'm so confused. I also get errors that my output variables are not defined, but that's just because the code can't run long enough to define them!

I'm inputting (0,1,0,-2,0,4) since I know the roots of that function and am trying to test it out.

Comment: It works for me! Try clearing the work space. Is it possible you have two functions with the same name?

Comment: I tried clearing everything and it still isn't running... the directory that I'm in has no other functions with this name.

Comment: Did you try what Dennis said? Type `edit bisect` in the command prompt in MATLAB? Can you try removing the two first lines and see if it runs? Just do `y = 1; z = 1;`. What do you get? And the same thing if you remove everything in the function. And what happens if you take everything from your function and copy-paste it into a new script and rename it and save it? Might be the best approach.

Comment: Have updated the answer as I suddenly realized that it was the second requested output argument that caused the touble. If you want to figure out why the `root` remains unassigned, just put a breakpoint in the code and step through it with f10 untill you reach the point where a value should be assigned.

Comment: I changed directories and was able to get something running, so maybe it's an issue within the directory.

Comment: Why should `root` cause problems @DennisJaheruddin? `roots` is built-in, not `root`. Or is it something else?

Comment: @RobertP. The if statements just never reached a place where a value was assigned to it given the example input. Probably a flaw in the logic but I didn't look at the content of the calculation.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. The `if` and `elseif` is identical. I'm not sure why OP didn't use `y` and `z` in the `elseif` statement too..? But my guess he should have switched less than and greater than.

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
bisect(0,1,0,-2,0,4)
```

and got:

```
ans =

There exists a root in [0,4].
```

This basically means the code itself works.

However, when I tried

```
[flag,root] = bisect(0,1,0,-2,0,4)
```

I got an error as `root` is not defined. The solution to this is making sure it is always defined. An easy way would be to add a line near the top like

```
root = NaN;
```